# Using ldply with unequal lengths from strsplit

Tags: r

I am trying to split a data frame column into multiple columns based on some delimiters. I have found various answers on this site, and I'm trying to get different ways to work. I'm having trouble with `ldply`. The problem is that the output of `strsplit` is a list of elements of different lengths. Here is some sample data, what has worked, and what I'm attempting with `ldply`.

```
FirstName <- c("a,b", "c d", "e, f", "gh")
OtherInfo <- c(1:4)
df <- data.frame(FirstName, OtherInfo, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df)

#Solution with cSplit
library(splitstackshape)
cs <- cSplit(df, "FirstName", "[, ]+", fixed = FALSE)


#Solution with strsplit and as.data.frame
#Feels like a hack, and I have "gh" repeated
#Question: Is there a better way using a similar approach?
df2 <- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(df$FirstName, "[, ]+", fixed = FALSE)))
row.names(df2) <- NULL


#Question: Solution with strsplit and plyr
library(plyr)
list1 <- strsplit(df$FirstName, "[, ]+", fixed = FALSE)
df3 <- ldply(list1)
```

Error:

```
#Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : 
#   Results do not have equal lengths
```

I wrote this fix to insert NA values, but it doesn't feel like the best way. Is there a better way?

```
MAX = max(sapply(list1, length))

func1 <- function(x, MAX) {
    vec <- c(x, rep(NA, MAX-length(x)))
    return(vec)    
}

list2 <- lapply(list1, func1, MAX = MAX)
list2

df3.1 <- ldply(list2)
```

Comment: In your real example, do you have words or just single letters?

Comment: Words. First and last names that get entered in different interesting ways.

Comment: Kevin , really anxious to know if my answer worked for you, or if you came up with a separate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one quick solution with dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

df4 <- df %>%
  mutate( parts = strsplit(FirstName, "[, ]+", fixed=FALSE) ) %>% 
  group_by( FirstName ) %>%
  do(  data.frame( 
    { 
      idx <- 1:length(.$parts[[1]])
      lst <- lapply(idx,
                    function(x) .$parts[[1]][x])
      names(lst) <- lapply(idx,
                           function(x) paste("Firstname",x,sep="") )

      (lst)
    } , stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  inner_join(df,by="FirstName")

print(df4)
```

For the provided example, I get:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: FirstName

  FirstName Firstname1 Firstname2 OtherInfo
1       a,b          a          b         1
2       c d          c          d         2
3      e, f          e          f         3
4        gh         gh         NA         4
```

The logic of the solution is as follows:
1. Split each first name into a list of parts
2. For each FirstName create a new data.frame such as the data comes from parts but variable names are FirstName1, FirstName2 etc
3. Merge the dataset back to the original so that to put OtherInfo back into it

Comment: Thanks. This is above my skill level. What do `%>%` and `.$parts` do? Are they special to plyr / dplyr? Accepting the answer as another possible solution, but for using plyr, I think my approach of appending NA's and using `ldply` is simpler.

Comment: I'll try to give a short high-level answer since the full explanation would require functional programming / dplyr. `%>%` is a chain operation in functional programming. Defined in  dplyr (and magrittr). More specifically, `x %>% y %>% z` is just a nicer way of saying `z(y(x))`. In other words, `df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(sum_y=sum(y))` is nothing more than `summarise( group_by(df,x), sum_y = sum(y))`. Basically, first group the data.frame by x and then report sum y for each x  `.$parts` is somewhat like `current_df$parts` but without `current_df` (dot is the current df inside `do()`).