# Using XML to associate the values of children and parent nodes

Tags: xml, r

When using R's XML package, how do I keep data from a certain node associated with that node, for example in the same list? I am trying to get data scraped from the web into a data frame with related information grouped into rows. There are `<span>` elements without class attributes to distinguish them, and there may be one or two `<span>`'s in each related group (row of the data frame).

Here is some example html that I saved as `html_example.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="fooname">Name of 1st foo</div>
            <span>1st span in 1st foo</span>
            <span>2nd span in 1st foo</span>
        </div>

        <div class="foo">
            <div class="fooname">Name of 2nd foo</div>
            <span>Only 1 span in 2nd foo</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the current parsing code and output:

```
library(XML)

html <- readLines("html_example.html")
parse <- htmlParse(html)

fooname <- xpathSApply(parse, "//div[@class='foo']/div[@class='fooname']"
    , xmlValue)
print(fooname)

    # > print(fooname)
    # [1] "Name of 1st foo" "Name of 2nd foo"

span <- xpathSApply(parse, "//div[@class='foo']/span"
    , xmlValue)
print(span)

    # >     print(span)
    # [1] "1st span in 1st foo"    "2nd span in 1st foo"    "Only 1 span in 2nd foo"
```

There is currently no way to relate the values of "fooname" and "span". Is there a way to get the scraping output to look something like this?

```
foo1 <- list(fooname[1], span[1:2])
foo2 <- list(fooname[2], span[3])
list1 <- list(foo1, foo2)
list1

    # > mylist
    # [[1]]
    # [[1]][[1]]
    # [1] "Name of 1st foo"
    # 
    # [[1]][[2]]
    # [1] "1st span in 1st foo" "2nd span in 1st foo"
    # 
    # 
    # [[2]]
    # [[2]][[1]]
    # [1] "Name of 2nd foo"
    # 
    # [[2]][[2]]
    # [1] "Only 1 span in 2nd foo"
```

Ultimately, not necessary during the scraping, I would like to create a data frame that looks like this. Relevant discussion on NAs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188801/using-ldply-with-unequal-lengths-from-strsplit/29189798#29189798):

```
FooNames <- c(fooname[1], fooname[2])
Span1 <- c(span[1], span[3])
Span2 <- c(span[2], NA)
df <- data.frame(FooNames, Span1, Span2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df

    # > df
    #          FooNames                  Span1               Span2
    # 1 Name of 1st foo    1st span in 1st foo 2nd span in 1st foo
    # 2 Name of 2nd foo Only 1 span in 2nd foo                <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a function to each of the nodes of interest (`div[class="foo"]` in this case). A simple example takes each node and applies xmlValue to the `div class="fooname"` and `span` subnodes. It then returns these values as a `data.frame`. You can bind the resulting data.frames together to get the desired result:

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="fooname">Name of 1st foo</div>
            <span>1st span in 1st foo</span>
            <span>2nd span in 1st foo</span>
        </div>

        <div class="foo">
            <div class="fooname">Name of 2nd foo</div>
            <span>Only 1 span in 2nd foo</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>' -> appData
doc <- htmlParse(appData)
myFunc <- function(x){
  div <- xpathSApply(x, "./div[@class='fooname']", fun = xmlValue)
  span <- xpathSApply(x, "./span", fun = xmlValue)
  data.frame(FooNames = div, Span1 = span[1], Span2 = span[2])
}
res <- doc["//*/div[@class='foo']", fun = myFunc]

> do.call(rbind, res)
FooNames                  Span1               Span2
1 Name of 1st foo    1st span in 1st foo 2nd span in 1st foo
2 Name of 2nd foo Only 1 span in 2nd foo                <NA>
```

Comment: I like the use of `span[2]` to put in the value or NA as appropriate. Is `doc["//*/div[@class='foo']", fun = myFunc]` the same as `xpathApply(doc, "//*/div[@class='foo']", fun = myFunc)`?

Comment: `[` is syntactic sugar for calling `getNodeSet` as can be seen in `getAnywhere("[.XMLInternalDocument")`

Comment: Thanks. I also got that line to work with `xpathApply`. I have also experimented at other times with `xpathApply` vs. `getNodeSet` and have trouble seeing the difference. Any tips?

Comment: Please see my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547506/assigning-variable-values-programmatically-during-html-parsing)