# Assigning variable values programmatically during html parsing

Tags: xml, r

I am expanding a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504327/using-xml-to-associate-the-values-of-children-and-parent-nodes/) about html parsing to include a question about blank values. Suppose I have empty values for certain variables that I am pulling from the HTML. There are multiple variables that could be empty, so I want a systematic approach to handling them (loop or function).

This question really is about assigning variables programmatically, and most of the information I have found suggests avoiding the use of `eval(parse(text`, but I'm not sure how to replace it in this case. I have the following HTML:

```
html <- 
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="fooname">Name of 1st foo</div>
            <div class="abc">ABC value only present here</div>
            <span>1st span in 1st foo</span>
            <span>2nd span in 1st foo</span>
        </div>

        <div class="foo">
            <div class="fooname">Name of 2nd foo</div>
            <span>Only 1 span in 2nd foo</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>'
```

Here is the parsing:

```
library(XML)

html.parse <- htmlParse(html)

myFunc <- function(x){
    fooname <- xpathSApply(x, "./div[@class='fooname']", fun = xmlValue)
    abc <- xpathSApply(x, "./div[@class='abc']", fun = xmlValue)
    span <- xpathSApply(x, "./span", fun = xmlValue)

    df <- data.frame(fooname, abc, Span1 = span[1], Span2 = span[2])
    return(df)
}

result <- getNodeSet(html.parse, "//div[@class='foo']", fun = myFunc)

#  Error in data.frame(fooname, abc, Span1 = span[1], Span2 = span[2]) : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Here is my attempted fix.

```
myFunc <- function(x){
    fooname <- xpathSApply(x, "./div[@class='fooname']", fun = xmlValue)
    abc <- xpathSApply(x, "./div[@class='abc']", fun = xmlValue)
    span <- xpathSApply(x, "./span", fun = xmlValue)


    dfvars <- c("fooname", "abc", "span")

    #I think I have the same issue about assigning a variable in `apply`
        #functions, right?

    for(var in dfvars) {

        if(length(eval(parse(text = var))) == 0) {
            cat("No ", var, " value found for this group.\n")

            #Note the "list" class:
            cat("Class of ", var, " is: ", class(eval(parse(text = var))), "\n")
            cat("Placing an NA.\n")

            #This line gives an error:
            assign(eval(parse(text = var)), as.character(NA))

            cat("new value of ", var, " : ", eval(parse(text = var)), "\n")
            cat("New length of ", var, " : ", length(eval(parse(text = var))), "\n")
            cat("New class of ", var, " : ", class(eval(parse(text = var))), "\n")

        }
    }

    df <- data.frame(fooname, abc, Span1 = span[1], Span2 = span[2])
    return(df)
}

result <- getNodeSet(html.parse, "//div[@class='foo']", fun = myFunc)

#  Error in assign(eval(parse(text = var)), as.character(NA)) : 
#   invalid first argument
```

Note that while here the `for` loop (or `apply` function if I do it that way) is in the second nesting layer. In my real project, it's in the third; the outer layer opens up each in a series of pages. It would be good to avoid going into a third level if possible, but I also want to keep things straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own `xpathSApply` function that tests for a `list()`:

```
myXpathSApply <- function(x, ...){
  y <- xpathSApply(x, ...)
  if(length(y) > 0){y}else{NA}
}
```

and use this function where you use `xpathSApply`:

```
myFunc <- function(x){
    fooname <- myXpathSApply(x, "./div[@class='fooname']", fun = xmlValue)
    abc <- myXpathSApply(x, "./div[@class='abc']", fun = xmlValue)
    span <- myXpathSApply(x, "./span", fun = xmlValue)

    df <- data.frame(fooname, abc, Span1 = span[1], Span2 = span[2])
    return(df)
}
```

Comment: Appears to be working great. Tried it on one page, now trying it on the rest. Is it a problem to have both layers of nested functions set as `function(x)` (and not changing `x` to something else)?

Comment: Worked great for the whole web scrape!